# handling time format in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, time, format

I have a mysql table which contains a field named **time** and has the "time" format. I added the first line into the table manually and its time is "14:55:00".

Now, in my PHP page, users will fill a form and then submit it. Here, I want my php to assign the last register's time value into a variable like `$time` (i can do that). Then I want this:

```
$time=$time + 5 minutes
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you already done?

Comment: `$time = strtotime('+5 minutes')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update your **sql** table, you can use the `DATE_ADD` function:

```
UPDATE table SET time = DATE_ADD(time, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

---

If you want to add 5 minutes to a timestamp in **PHP** you can use the function `strtotime`:

```
$time = $time + strtotime("+5 minutes");
```

If your time is a string (ie in format 14:55:00), you can do the following:

```
$timeAsString = "14:55:00";
$timestamp = strtotime("+5 minutes", strtotime($timeAsString));
$time = date("H:i:s", $timestamp);

echo $time;
```

Comment: I did this but... first `echo $time;` -> output: 14:55:00 then I did what you said and the result is: `1400948613` EDIT: I need the second one you said.

Comment: tha returned error 500. As I said in my first post, I fetch the last time from the db. And in the db, its data type is "time". So I think it is not string. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: 14:55:00 became 06:46:36. Why is that?

Comment: I made an update. This will work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $dateMinutes= date("i")+5;
```

and use  the [make time](http://php.net/mktime) function from php

Comment: this won't work, because you can get minutes >= 60

Comment: `mktime` handles it well: If you have minutes = 65, the date('i') becomes equal 5, and hour is incremented.

Comment: Yes, but not if time is already > 55 (i.e: when date('i') returns already 57)